# Why is $\int_{\Omega}X^+\,dP = \int _{0}^{\infty}P(X^+ > t)\,dt$?

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, statistics, lebesgue-integral, fubini-tonelli-theorems

$X$ be a random variable and $P$ is a probability measure on $\Omega$. Is it true that $$\displaystyle{\int_{\Omega}}X^+\,\mathrm{d}P = \displaystyle{\int _{0}^{\infty}}P(X^+ > t)\,\mathrm{d}t\,, $$

where $X^+(\omega)=\max\{X(\omega),0\}\,$?

I was thinking along the guidelines of Fubini's theorem as probability is a $\sigma$-finite measure.
The left hand side of the integral is actually area under a curve taking vertical strips and the right hand side is calculating the same area taking horizontal strips. So by Fubini's theorem they must be equal.

But how do I rigorously show this ?

Comment: Exactly as you described it - maybe use Tonelli's theorem for the case when the LHS/RHS do not converge.

Answer (score 3):

First note that $\displaystyle{\int _{0}^{\infty}}P(X^+ > t)dt =\displaystyle{\int _{0}^{\infty}}\int 1(X^+ > t)\, dP\,dt $, where $1(A)$ is the indicator function of the event $A$. Then use [Tonelli's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fubini%27s_theorem#Tonelli%27s_theorem_for_non-negative_measurable_function) to interchange the integral and get
$$
\displaystyle{\int _{0}^{\infty}}\int 1(X^+ > t)\, dP\,dt =\int \displaystyle{\int _{0}^{\infty}}1(X^+ > t)\, dt\,dP = \int \displaystyle{\int _{0}^{X^+}}\, dt\,dP =\int {X^+}\,dP.
$$

Comment: So if I am working with a random variable whose expectation is finite then this is basically by Fubini's theorem right ?

Comment: Correct. Generally speaking, you do not need to bother about the finiteness when the integrand is non-negative. You can just use Tonelli.

Comment: Thank you so much